# How to make my code ask the user for input again python

Tags: python

I'm creating a python program that gives you the area for any shape you enter and I want to know how to make the program **return to asking the user what shape they want**

```
import math

user_choice = input("Choose a shape")

if user_choice == "rectangle" or "square":
    a = input("enter your length in centimeters here")
    b = input("enter your width in centimeters here")

    area = int(a) * int (b)
    print(area, "cm²")
else
    print"Sorry, you may have made a spelling error, or have chose a shape that we cannot calculate. Please try again"
#Code that returns to first question here?
```

Also if possible, since the code is very long because it is just repeating the if statements as elif statements for new shapes, is there a way to shorten it so it isn't lots of elif statements.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: `while` loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
import math

done = 'n'
while done == 'n':
     user_choice = input("Choose a shape")

     if user_choice == "rectangle" or "square":
         a = input("enter your length in centimeters here")
         b = input("enter your width in centimeters here")

         area = int(a) * int (b)
         print(area, "cm²")
     else
         print("Sorry, you may have made a spelling error, or have chose a shape that we cannot calculate. Please try again")
     done = input("Done? (Y/N)").lower()
```